# Java Splash Screen Location

Tags: java, splash-screen

I created a Java application that uses a [Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).
Now this splash screen shows up in the center of the desktop. Unfortunately my desktop (and that of many other users) consists of two screen side by side. The window that renders in the center always is split between the two screens.

How can my application control where the Splash Screen will show up? Is there any way to change the default behaviour?

One idea would be to remember the position where the application window was used last time and center the splash screen there.

Comment: The referenced answers all direct to creating a splash screen either using JWindow or an undecorated JFrame. As soon as you use setLocationRelativeTo(null) the window gets positioned in the center of the first screen. Problem solved.